# Exception from sub books id dMBTck6CaSupWbEna TypeError: Cannot read property ‘emails’ of null

Tags: meteor

I am getting an Exception whenever a user logged in into his account, and I cant see the collection data until the page is been refreshed… **[but I am not getting any exception if I use it like

```
Books.find({“customer_name”:this.userId);
```

instead of

```
Books.find({“customer_name”:Meteor.user().emails[0].address);
```

and I don't need that step because in my app users collection finding should be based on their email id, not by userId…]**
my code is shown below :
Someone, please help me out:frowning_face:

server - main.js:

```
var My_collection;
Meteor.publish(‘books’, function() {
My_collection = 
Books.find({“customer_name”:Meteor.user().emails[0].address);
return My_collection;
```

client -main.js:

```
Template.viewBooks.helpers({
books() {
return Books.find({}, { sort: { books_order: -1 } }).fetch();
},
});
```

client - main.html

```
{{#each books}}
{{books_id}} 
{{/each}}
```

ERROR:

> App running at: http://localhost:3000/ I20171205-16:06:49.773(5.5)?
>   Exception from sub transactions id wQ9DpjjABEiPzMZ9P TypeError: Cannot
>   read property ‘emails’ of null I20171205-16:06:49.872(5.5)? at
>   Subscription._handler (server/main.js:16:75)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.873(5.5)? at maybeAuditArgumentChecks
>   (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1768:12)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.873(5.5)? at
>   DDP.CurrentPublicationInvocation.withValue
>   (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1043:15)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.873(5.5)? at
>   Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1134:15)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.873(5.5)? at Subscription.runHandler
>   (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:1041:51)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.873(5.5)? at
>   packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:826:41
>   I20171205-16:06:49.874(5.5)? at Function..each..forEach
>   (packages/underscore.js:147:22) I20171205-16:06:49.874(5.5)? at
>   packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:822:9
>   I20171205-16:06:49.874(5.5)? at
>   Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1134:15)
>   I20171205-16:06:49.874(5.5)? at Session._setUserId
>   (packages/ddp-server/livedata_server.js:816:34)

Answer (score 0):

It’s generally bad practice to use Meteor.user() on the server. Without having enough information surrounding how you’re publishing and subscribing to your collections, and since you’re saying you aren’t getting any errors when you use this.userId, you can find the email address the following way:

```
var currentUser = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
var userEmail = currentUser.emails[0].address;
```

Then use it in Books.find

If you can provide more information about the subscription and the publication, i’d be able to help out more